# Blog - BlogPost - BlogPostComment vs Blog - Post - Comment

Tags: naming

Don't really know how to formulate the title, but it should be pretty obvious from the example.

More specifically, what rules do you use for naming "dependent" classes. For example, `Blog` is a pretty descriptive name itself, but how do I deal with posts? `BlogPost` or `Post`? Clearly, first name clearly expresses that it's a "subordinate" class, but this can quickly get out of hand with `BlogPostComment`, `BlogPostCommentAttachment`, etc. `Post`, on the other hand, looks like an entity completely unrelated to `Blog` and is easier on the eye.

What are your rules/best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you mention, the problem is so well known as it makes no difference to be terse, and it actually saves you typing. Other types of relationships between classes aren't so cut-and-dry.

Another plus to using "Blog", "Post" and "Comment" is that you could reuse Post and Comment for other stuff not necessarily blog-related, and they'd fit better there (ok, it's just a rename anyway).

My rule would then be 'be as clear as you can'. I do tend to assume that, before you come barging in on my code, or I start a project guns ablaze, we have read a bit about the problem space.

Furthermore: most web frameworks I know make things *much* easier to use terse names like Blog, Post, etc. for model names.

Answer (score 3):

I personally like the latter best. And wouldn't a good namespace-name disambiguate `Post`?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I would use either depending on the situation.

For example a simple News and NewsItem would be fine as it's a basic model and the naming convention makes the relation clear in this case.

However, for larger developments with more complex domain models and well maintained namespacing (for example a blog) I would say it's must less convoluted and cleaner to name the types Blog, Post, Comment.

Comment: I'd think the opposite: in a small project, it makes no difference because it's easily understandable, and in a complex domain you have to use proper namespaces (in one way or the other) to keep everything together.